# JPA construct looking for wrong constructor

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

We are trying to use JPAs `construct()` API to map data into our objects, but unfortunately it seems to ignore the type conversion:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ReportDto> q = cb.createQuery(ReportDto.class);
q.select(cb.construct(DailyReportDto.class, r.get(createdYear),
    r.get(KpiSnapshot_.createdDay),
    cb.toLong(cb.avg(r.get(KpiSnapshot_.value)))));
```

results in:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DailyReportDto.<init>(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Double)
```

which doesn't make sense to me, because `toLong` should prevent it from looking for a Double, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toLong and other CriteriaBuilder methods of that form do not create new expressions or alter them in anyway - they are used for casting, changing the generic type of the expression.  Your expression will still be b.avg(r.get(KpiSnapshot_.value)), which will still be a Double.

Your constructor will need to handle converting Double to Long if required.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your explaination. Even though the it's a Expression<Long> after the toLong call, it will still return a Double?

Comment: yes.  It is same as casting anything - it doesn't change the object itself.  So if the expression was going to return a double, it still will.  This is meant for other expressions, such as Expression<number> where you may know it will be a Long type returned and need to use it as such.

Comment: Strange, but makes sense (somehow). But shouldn't Expresion.as(Long.class) work then? According to the javadocs it's creating a new Expression object. Or is it still just a typecasted clone of the original Expression?

Comment: Expresion.as(Long.class)  returns a new expression but the javadoc states it is only typecasting and "This method does not cause type conversion: the runtime type is not changed."  Changing from Double to Long requires conversions, not casting